# Search input focus not work

Tags: jquery-mobile

on a simple search input

```
$('#search-basic').val(''); // and value is correctly deleted
$('#search-basic').focus(); // highlighted but no cursor inside input
$('#search-basic').trigger('change');  // not work (result list not deleted)
```

I've tried

```
setTimeout(function(){$('#search-basic').focus()}, 50);
```

or

```
$("#search-basic").focus(function() {
$(this).val('');
$(this).trigger('change');
$(this).select();
});
$("#search-basic").mouseup(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
$('#search-basic').focus();
```

same results....

Answer (score 0):

Are you using unique ID's?

If you are using a "text" input element try using keyup instead of mouseup.

Do you have any supporting HTML?

Edit:

Try:

```
$("#search-basic").bind("focus", function(){
  $(this).val("").change();
}).bind("keypress", function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    return false;
  }
});
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#search-basic').focus();
});
```

This will sort the focus on click for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("li div a").bind("mouseup", function(){
        $('#search-basic').focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: unique id, tried keyup same result  HTML `<div style="padding:0.8em;"> <h2>Ricerca articolo:</h2> <input type="search" onkeyup="ArticlesSearchView.render();" name="search" id="search-basic" value="" /> <ul id="articles" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" > </ul> </div>`

Comment: @user1374583 I have added some code, I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do could you explain in greater detail, thanks

Comment: after select one item in serch list on a button click return focus on search input field cleaning search result.

Comment: it not works also when I render for the first time my search input:
I can't focus my search input programmatically.

Comment: I have updated the code to focus once the documant has loaded

Comment: setTimeout(function(){$('#search-basic').focus();}, 500);  it' works on document ready

Comment: I thing there is some other focus called after render my page. now it work with timeout.... 
    `<li data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-corner-top ui-btn-up-c">
    <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li ui-corner-top">
    <div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#" id="421590280" onclick="window.rmsApp.selectArticle('421590280')" class="ui-link-inherit">
    421590280 ITEM DESC ITEM PRICE BSA<br>DESC | Categ</a>
    </div>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span></div></li>`

Comment: `selectArticle: function(code){
         var artSel = Articles.searchWithCode(code);
         window.currentArticleView = new ArticleView({model: artSel});
         window.currentArticleView.render();
           $('<a/>').attr('href', '#pageAddProduct').attr('data-rel', 'dialog').click();
        }`